# jpeg to png conversion

Tags: iphone, windows-xp, png, jpeg

I am working on images in iPhone. There are lots of jpeg images which range from 35kb to 50kb. I may need to transfer this over internet which comes around 6 mb. I tried to change a 35kb jpeg image to png. The actual size got increase jpeg was 56.1kb and png is 576 kb. I used mspaint to change the format. jpeg to png should actually decrease the size of the image right ? If no is that ideal to have jpeg files on iphone or only png like typical mobile applications have ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPEG and PNG are very different file formats; any given image that is smaller in one may not be smaller in another. And furthermore, their quality is *not* directly comparable.

For example, photographic content is very well represented in JPEG. The subdivision-of-blocks composed with pattern recognition makes for a format that does a very good job of discarding visual information in a way that human eyes do not easily notice. Of course, a highly-compressed JPEG may throw away *too* much information and show the blocks and instantly break the illusion of photographic reality, but used carefully, JPEG is fantastic for photos of the 'real world'.

And computer-generated content is very well represented in PNG. The lossless encoding is great for showing the straight lines of standard computer-generated displays, and naively-created gradients are replicated exactly with PNG. Had JPEG been used for either straight lines or naive gradients, the shortcomings would stand out instantly. Also, because PNG can be palette-based, it can very efficiently store images with only a few dozen colors.

So, pick the file format based on its use: JPEG for photos of reality or for very good approximations of reality, and PNG for computer-generated content.

Answer (score 1):

PNG files are usually smaller if their contents are graphical and contain a lot of evenly colored shapes. For photos or scans jpeg files are way smaller, since they use a much more sophisticated, yet lossy, algorithm for compression.

For your iPhone project you should use whatever is smaller, in your case jpeg.